# Standardizing Docker Container OS

Tags: docker

In most organizations I've worked in we usually standardize around an OS for most of our systems. It seems like in the Dockersphere you either are at the whim of the author of the official Docker image, you need to hunt around for the exact image you need or you build your own. So if you go the more time efficient route you might end up with a mish-mash of container OS's.

My question is, is standardizing around an OS still something Docker-enabled organizations do or is that dinosaur thinking?

Answer (score 0):

Standardizing on an OS delivers offers the promise of a consistent operating environment for deployed applications. Docker containers provide even stronger consistency, regardless of OS. Each container shares only the Kernel of the host machine.

Building containers, on the other hand, still require package repositories. 
Many organisations will mirror repositories and standardizing on an OS reduces this maintenance burden.